# What's the difference: {hsize, linewidth, textwidth, pagewidth}?

Tags: latex

What is the difference between `\hsize`, `\linewidth`, `\textwidth` and `\pagewidth`? Which are affected by environments (like an enumeration or a minipage)? Did I miss any useful width lengths?

Comment: To me it looks like this question has meanwhile been answered at tex.se: [Difference between \textwidth, \linewidth and \hsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize)

Comment: @quazgar - Neither the tex.sx question nor its accepted answer discuss the `\pagewidth` dimension.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many more lengths useful to layout in LaTeX.  The ones related to "page" layout are mostly here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout

\linewidth is width of text in current environment.

I myself am not sure about how \hsize relates to the others, although I think it's supposed to be the width of text on the page.

Answer (score 16):

The various dimensions ending in `width` are part of Latex and not primitives of the underlying Tex engine, unlike `\hsize` which is the Tex primitive described in Alexey's answer.  `\textwidth` usually does not change while a Latex document is being typeset, and should normally be the width of the bounding box in which all the text inside paragraphs sit in; this will usually be the same as `\hsize`.

`\linewidth` is a contextual dimension that becomes narrower in environments with indentation, such as list environments.  It should be the actual width of the current paragraph and should be less than or equal to `\textwidth`.  `\pagewidth` should be the width of the whole page, including margins: this should normally be larger than `\textwidth`.

But of course with macro hackery, you can break any rule you feel like.

Answer (score 7):

`\hsize` is a TeX primitive. It is always the width of the current paragraph. `\hsize` is set at the `\begin{document}` point depending on `\textwidth`, 1-page or 2-page and the marging.

Comment: You have `\hsize` twice, is the second supposed to be `\pagewidth`?